# Value set using JavaScript is not persisted on Postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have two list controls in my asp.net page and am populating the second list control using javascript. Problem is the script executes and i can see the value moved from first list box (ConfiguredOrgListBox) to second list box(SelectedOrgListBox) but when i try to save using submit button i find my second list as empty and first list box as it was earlier. Below is the script and mark up.

```
    //call this method to register the script    
    private void CreateMoveOrganizationScript(StringBuilder sb) {
        sb.Append( @"<script language=javascript type=text/javascript>;
                    function moveOrganisation() {");            
        sb.Append( @"var source = document.getElementById('"+ ConfiguredOrgListBox.ClientID  +@"');
                    var target = document.getElementById('"+SelectedOrgListBox.ClientID+ @"');
                    if ((source != null) && (target != null)) {
                    var newOption = new Option();
                    newOption.text = source.options[source.options.selectedIndex].text;
                    newOption.value = source.options[source.options.selectedIndex].value;

                    target.options[target.length] = newOption;
                    source.remove(source.options.selectedIndex)  ;
                    }            
                } </script>");            
    }
```

Markup

```
      <asp:Label ID="ConfiguredOrgLabel" runat="server" Text="Available Organizations"></asp:Label><br />
      <asp:ListBox ID="ConfiguredOrgListBox" runat="server" Width="98%" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
       <input id="MoveOrgRight" type="button" value=">>" onclick="moveOrganisation()" />
      <asp:Label ID="SelectedOrgLabel" runat="server" Text="Selected VNA Organizations"></asp:Label><br />
      <asp:ListBox ID="SelectedOrgListBox" runat="server" Width="98%" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Regards,
JeeZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.dotnet-developer.de/2008/07/aspnet2005/ajax/using-javascript-on-listboxes-in-aspnet/), it's because the list box doesn't post back to tell the back-end that it's changed. They use a hidden field which holds info on what changes were made with JavaScript and then on postback it updates the back-end.

Comment: Thanks Andrew & Drackir, Am new to java script asn asp.net so was not aware of this concept. I have one question list control and hidden filed both are WebControl if we can  set value of hidden control we should be able to set value of list control too right ( they should behave in same way!!)... Drackir I tried what was suggested in the link but some how even that did not work, when i debugged i found that the hidden field is getting initialized but on the server side the value of hidden field is empty !! :(

Comment: Are the controls definitely in the same `<form>` as the submit button?

Comment: yeah they are in the same form but different <div> section, guess that should not be a problem

Comment: I don't suppose the form fields (hidden or otherwise) are disabled? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770508/client-side-js-and-asp-net-postback) question which had a similar problem with text fields being disabled and ignored.

Comment: Thanks for responding and helping me solve the issue ... that questions and response helped me understand the concepts better ... I wrote a small asp.net program where in i populate a textbox on a html button click using java script and display the populated value on submit button click ... the program worked with out any assistance of hidden field i was wondering for the list do we need the hidden field or the control can persist changes without hidden field .. will investigate and publish the result .. thanks again for your time i appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to process these changes during postback. When postback happens ASP.NET engine loads control's data from view state and it doesn't know that client modified values using javascript, so you should manually extract those values from Request.